# What are some interesting/useful examples of "ambiently homeomorphic" subsets of $\mathbb R^m$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We say that two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R^m$ are *ambiently homeomorphic* if there exists a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to itself which maps $A$ onto $B$ or visa versa.

Why do we care about ambient homeomorphisms? I asked my professor and he literally told me "because they are interesting."

So what are some examples where ambient homeomorphisms are either

- useful in proofs, or
- have interesting applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knots in $S^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ are only interesting if studied under ambient homeomorphism (or isotopy), since any two knots are homeomorphic (they are both copies of $S^1$).

[This famous paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1989-02-02/S0894-0347-1989-0965210-7/S0894-0347-1989-0965210-7.pdf) by C. Gordon and J. Luecke shows that two knots are equivalent (in the sense of the existence of an ambient homeomorphism which takes one knot to the other) if and only if their complements are homeomorphic. This result implies that prime knot (complements) with isomorphic fundamental groups are equivalent (Corollary 2.1 in paper), so you can genuinely study prime knots by studying $\pi_1$, which reduces complexity in many ways.

Comment: Note that this cannot tell the difference between a knot and its mirror image (which are related by an ambient homeomorphism but not necessarily by an ambient isotopy).